# Deleting discord.py 2.0 everytime bot gets reseted

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im currently using replit and whenever I install discord.py 2.0 with pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py, it works well and properly but whenever it gets kill 1'd or reseted(I dont know what the term is), it deletes discord.py 2.0 and goes back to discord.py 1.7.3, which is annoying since I have to install discord.py 2.0 right after that. I cant provide any more details and I believe showing the code itself isnt very necessary, but if there may be a problem with that, then tell me in the comments and ill add the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you want to update discord.py before you run your bot. In order to do so, you can add this line after your imports:

```py
os.system("python3 -m pip install -U discord.py")
```